# Partial Ngrx/Redux Application

Tags: angularjs, redux, ngrx

We have a large application written in angular(2 yr project), where in most screens it doesn't make sense to have a redux solution. But there are 6 or 7 screens in the whole application that have multiple sections/frames with updates and would work great with a redux solution.

Is it okay to have a Store, just to deal with these 6 screens, or do we need to design the whole application using the redux design ?

Comment: yes, I would say its ok. Redux creates a level of indirection that has benefits but also has tradeoffs.  You might not need it: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367.

Comment: One thing to be wary of is that you'll need to make sure the non-Redux parts of the application don't directly mutate state held within the store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends.

Reasons to put it into the store for pages that do not have much state updates:

1. Caching.  Say you make an api call and you save the data in the store for a page that has no state updates.  Then another page that requires state updates uses this same data.  By having the data in the store you save yourself an api call.
2. Consistency across the application.
3. You get used to using the redux dev tools and now you have pages on your site that redux dev tools can't help you with.  For example on a project I worked on we did decide to make certain pages use ngrx and other pages not use ngrx.  The problem was that we created an observable on the non ngrx page and we forgot to unsubscribe from it.  Well, this observable caused havoc on the ngrx parts of the site and we kept looking at the redux dev tools to determine what was wrong.  The redux dev tools couldn't help us since this observable was outside of ngrx.

Reasons not to put it into the store for certain pages:

1. Angular provides modules so you can scope the ngrx logic into specific modules.  So you can smartly only put it into modules that actually need it.
2. There's overhead to using ngrx.  If all you need to do is make a bunch of api calls then angular's resolve might be a better solution.

Comment: I think we will go with your first approach,scoping the ngrx logic to specific modules. thanks !